# If else statement in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel spreadsheet document with two sheets.

1. First sheet is called "Input" and has three columns and 5 rows.

   - What I first want is to merge the two values in the two first columns with a dash between them and return this value in the third column. (cell1Value-cell2Value).
   - Second I would like to remove the dash from the value returned in the second row, third column, if there is no value in the second column.
   - If there is no value in the first column I would like the third column to be blank, even if there is a value in the second column. (I want the same result if the two first columns are without a value).
2. Then in my next sheet "Output" I would like to store all my third columns with a value.

Sheet 1 (Input):
[image]

Sheet 2 (output):
[image]

Comment: The “Input” sheet part of this is very easy.  The “Output” sheet part is not hard.  There are hundreds of questions on [SU] alone showing how to do things like this.  What research have you done?  What have you tried?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I agree with Scott except your last entry on Sheet2 is modified.  Is that a typo or is there detail that has been left out of the question?

Answer (score 1):

**This method will fix the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `D28`, fill it down.

  ```
  =IF(AND(A28<>"",B28<>""),A28&"-"&B28,IF(A28<>"",A28,""))
  ```
- An Array Formula in Cell `A1` in `Sheet 2`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down.

`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!D$28:D$36,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!D$28:D$36<>"",ROW(Sheet1!D$28:D$36)-ROW(Sheet1!D$28)+1),ROWS(A$1:A1))),"")}`

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed*

Comment: Slight simplification for D: `=IF(A28="","",A28&IF(B28="","","-"&B28))`

Comment: @fixer1234,, yeah this can be used also ,, thanks ☺